# Java EE/JPA Integration testing with Rollback like in Spring

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, junit, integration-testing

In my current project I'm using Java EE and JPA. I'm now confronted with the need to persist stuff and, working test driven, I try to figure out how to test this stuff.

In a former project with Spring we used @Transactional(Rollback=true) to roll back the transactions after each test. We could call persist + flush and then query to check if the JPA was done correctly.

How do you do this elegantly (minimal configuration work, least possible extra stuff/resources) in Java EE?

jeeunit looked like an answer, but it is no longer continued but merged into 'pax exam' that does only provide maven support which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit  are meant to tests methods, there should be at least 2 tests per method: One sunny day and one rainy day. What happens out of the method should not matter. In this way I would go with some mock framework (mockito) to mock access to data base since reading/writing/deleting data in a database happens out of any method.

If you still want to test data consolidation into database I would use some in memory database such as HSQL or H2. This will allow to create your own database meant for testing purposes. Finally you should create the database after every execution of every test method in the junit class. To do this you should use:
**@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)**

This will make the test execution a bit slower but it will guarantee the test independence.

Comment: Hi KFleischer, was this info useful for you?

Comment: I believe that your approach works but in memory DBs are not available in out project. That's why I was asking for a app server solution. But this topic was 6y ago. ;-)